# Configure proxy server for docker

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, proxy-server

I have installed docker. when i try to run hello-world for testing on docker. i get following error
could not connect to daemon docker

with compose
ERROR: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)

my computer is using proxy server for communication. i need to configure that server in the docker. i know proxy server address and port. where i need to update this setting.

thanks.

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/network/proxy/